# Mapbox SDK Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I got to put the map in my app and running in my mobile, but I don't get to put the overlay file GeoJson from Assets Folder in the my locate folder in PC. I want to overlay the points from GeoJson and show popups of points' id. How could I do this?

Below the code that I made from tutorials in Mapbox site in Android Studio

````
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Style;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.sources.GeoJsonSource;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MapView mapView;
    private final String SOURCE_ID = "SOURCE_ID";
    private final String ICON_ID = "ICON_ID";
    private final String LAYER_ID = "LAYER_ID";
    private final String TAG = "TAG";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.access_token));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
                mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.DARK, new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                        try {
                            GeoJsonSource layer = new GeoJsonSource("mapView", new URI("assets://covid_unidades.geojson"));
                            style.addSource(layer);
                        } catch (URISyntaxException excepcion) {
                            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(excepcion));
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
} ```
````

Comment: What do you want to show using GeoJson.Markers on map? What do mean by  "popups of points' id". Can you explain problem in detail using may be images.